# st_buffer with geometry sfc_POINT

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf, rgeo-shapefile

I'm working with geospatial data and for one part of the analysis I need to use coordinate points of regions that I get from an excel and turn that data into sf object using `st_as_sf`. When I tried to set a buffer around the points I use `st_buffer(data_as_sf, 2000)` for a 2km buffer. This was working well with shapefiles where I had the geometry object as `sfc_MULTIPOLYGON`. But now my geometry object is `sfc_POINT`. How do I need to set the buffer in this case? Would it work well using regular `st_buffer` method or do I need to convert it into `sfc_MULTIPOLYGON`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply test it out?

```r
library(sf)

my_point <- st_sfc(st_point(c(0, 0)))

my_buffer <- st_buffer(my_point, 2000)

class(my_point)
#> [1] "sfc_POINT" "sfc"
class(my_buffer)
#> [1] "sfc_POLYGON" "sfc"

plot(my_buffer, axes = TRUE)
plot(my_point, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

We can see that `st_buffer` has correctly created a 2,000m `sfc_POLYGON` around our `sfc_POINT`

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Its not 2,000m unless you assign a coordinate system in metres. This is 2,000 unknown units...

Comment: @Spacedman yes, that's fair enough. I was guessing that the OP was working with a crs that was in metres, but I could be wrong about that.